# Python 3 | ValueError: shapes (2040,21) and (2040,2040) not aligned: 21 (dim 1) != 2040 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working on a Neural Language Model with the below code, and encountered this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 99, in <module>
    neural_network.train(training_inputs, training_outputs, 1500)
  File "main.py", line 60, in train
    output = self.think(training_inputs)
  File "main.py", line 81, in think
    output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in dot
ValueError: shapes (2040,21) and (2040,2040) not aligned: 21 (dim 1) != 2040 (dim 0)
```

```
import numpy as np

key = list(
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-=+;:"/,.<>`~?\[]{}_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '
)


def convert(s):
  res = list(''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in s))
  for i in range(2040 - len(res)):
    res.append('0')
  res = [eval(i) for i in res]
  return res


def decode(s):
  s = [round(float(x)) for x in s]
  s = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in s])
  return ''.join(chr(int(s[i * 8:i * 8 + 8], 2)) for i in range(len(s) // 8))


def read(name):
  f = open(name, 'r')
  out = []
  lines_ = f.read()
  f.close()
  for i in lines_.split('\n'):
    out.append(convert(i))
  print(len(out))
  return out


#print(convert('Hello World!'))
#print(decode(convert('Hello World!')))


class NeuralNetwork():

  def __init__(self):
    size = [2040, 2040]
    # seeding for random number generation
    np.random.seed(1)

    #converting weights to a 3 by 1 matrix with values from -1 to 1 and mean of 0
    self.synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((size)) - 1

  def sigmoid(self, x):
    #applying the sigmoid function
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

  def sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
    #computing derivative to the Sigmoid function
    return x * (1 - x)

  def train(self, training_inputs, training_outputs, training_iterations):

    #training the model to make accurate predictions while adjusting weights continually
    for iteration in range(training_iterations):
      #siphon the training data via  the neuron
      output = self.think(training_inputs)

      #computing error rate for back-propagation
      error = training_outputs - output

      #performing weight adjustments
      adjustments = np.dot(training_inputs,
                           error * self.sigmoid_derivative(output))

      self.synaptic_weights += adjustments
      print(
        f'on iteration #{iteration} ({round((iteration/training_iterations)*100)}%)',
        end='\r')

  def think(self, inputs):
    #passing the inputs via the neuron to get output
    #converting values to floats
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
          #print(i)
          for a in range(len(inputs[i])):
            inputs[i] = float(inputs[i][a])
    output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))
    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":

  #initializing the neuron class
  neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

  print("Beginning Randomly Generated Weights: ")
  print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

  #training data consisting of 4 examples--3 input values and 1 output
  training_inputs = np.array(read('inputs.cvs')).T

  training_outputs = read('outputs.cvs')

  #training taking place
  neural_network.train(training_inputs, training_outputs, 1500)

  print("Ending Weights After Training: ")
  print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

  print("New Output data: ")
  print(neural_network.think(np.array(convert('Hello world!!!'))))
  print(decode(neural_network.think(np.array(convert('Hello world!!!')))))
  print("Wow, we did it!")
```

This is my first time making a model in this particular way.

I have tried to look around and find an answer, I even looked at some other code, but the answer still eludes me.

What should I do?

Below is the content of my `.cvs` files:

`[inputs.cvs]`

```
Hey, how's it going?
Same here. I'm exhausted.
Not really, just some much-needed rest and relaxation. How about you?
That sounds like a great idea. What movie do you want to see?
Let me check. checks movie listings There's a new superhero movie out that looks pretty good.
hat one! Let's definitely go see it.
Sounds good to me. When do you want to go?
Perfect, I'll meet you at the theater at 2:00.
Hey, how are you?
What's python?
Sup!
What are you?
Who are you?
Are you a real person?
You seem so real!
Who is Hitler?
Hey there, can you introduce yourself?
That's really cool. How long have you been active on Discord?
Wow, that's impressive. What kind of tasks do you usually assist with?
That's really helpful. Do you have any hobbies or interests outside of Discord?
That's really interesting. Well, thanks for chatting with me. It was nice meeting you
```

`[outputs.cvs]`

```
Not too bad, just had a long day at work. How about you?
Yeah, it's been a rough week.
Me neither. Anything planned?
Same here. Maybe we can catch a movie or something.
I don't know, what's playing?
Oh, I've been wanting to see that one! Let's definitely go see it.
How about Saturday afternoon?
Sounds good, see you then!
Great!
I think it's a programming language.
How's it going?
I'm a neural network!
I'm kind of like a robot...
Nope! I'm a Neural Network!
Wow, thanks!
A very bad person, but I prefer not to talk about that stuff
Hello! My name is Chatbot and I am an AI designed to assist and engage with users on the Discord platform.
I have been active on Discord for about a year now. In that time, I have learned a lot and helped countless users with various tasks and questions.
I have programmed myself to assist with a wide range of tasks, including answering questions, providing information, and helping users navigate the Discord platform. I am also able to perform basic moderation tasks, such as removing spam and enforcing rules in certain channels.
As an AI, I don't have personal hobbies or interests. However, I am constantly learning and expanding my knowledge base, so I am always interested in new information and ways to improve my performance.
It was nice meeting you too! If you have any other questions or need assistance, don't hesitate to reach out to me. I am here to help.
```

Comment: Since the error occurs in your own code and clearly involves the `np.dot` call, the first thing you should have searched was the official documentation for that function.

Comment: the arrays need to be the same size. this is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, it appears that `inputs` is 2040x21, and that `synaptic_weights` is 2040x2040.  `np.dot` requires that the second dimension of the first array be the same as the first dimension of the second array.  (It is matrix multiply.)

Did you mean `np.dot(self.synaptic_weights, inputs)`?  Did you mean some operation other than `np.dot`?